# Slow Regex Split

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am parsing a large quantity of data (over 2GB), and my regex search is quite slow. Is there anyway to improve it?

**Slow Code**

```
string file_content = "4980: 01:06:59.140 - SomeLargeQuantityOfLogEntries";
List<string> split_content = Regex.Split(file_content, @"\s+(?=\d+: \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} - )").ToList();
```

The way the program works is as follows:

- Loads all the data into a string.
- The above line of code is used to split the string into log entries and store each entry as an entry in a list. (This is the slow part that I would like to optimize)
- Log entries are denoted by the Regex pattern shown above.

Comment: Read per line (asynchronously), split by known delimiters/ by fixed length, do this in parallel multitasks.

Comment: My advice, don't do it that way. Loading an entire file in as a string and then pointing Regex at it works with small files. At 2 Gig (that, btw, is an app's entire virtual memory space on a 32-bit box), it's definitely not the way to go. Instead, stream the file into memory, parsing as you. If the resulting list is eventually persisted to disk,  stream it out as you parse the input. It's more work, but it should be way faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the answer below I put couple of optimizations which you may use.
tl;dr; Speed up log parsing in 6 times by iterating the lines and use custom parsing method (not Regex)

#### Measurements

Before we attempt to make optimizations I'd propose to define how are we going to measure their impact and value.

For benchmarking I'll use [Benchmark.NET](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) framework. Create console application:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<LogReaderBenchmarks>();
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<LogParserBenchmarks>();
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<LogBenchmarks>();
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
```

Run below command in `PackageManagerConsole` to add nuget package:

```
Install-Package BenchmarkDotNet -Version 0.11.5
```

Test data generator looks like this, run it once, and then just use that temp file all over your benchmarks:

```
public static class LogFilesGenerator {

        public static void GenerateLogFile(string location)
        {
            var sizeBytes = 512*1024*1024; // 512MB
            var line = new StringBuilder();
            using (var f = new StreamWriter(location))
            {
                for (long z = 0; z < sizeBytes; z += line.Length)
                {
                    line.Clear();
                    line.Append($"{z}: {DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff")} - ");
                    for (var l = -1; l < z % 3; l++)
                        line.AppendLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                    f.WriteLine(line);
                }
                f.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Reading file

And commentators pointed - that is very inefficient to read the whole file to memory, GC will be very unhappy, let's read it line-by-line.

The simplest way to achieve this is just using `File.ReadLines()` method which returns you non-materialized enumerable - you'll read the file while you are iterating over it.

You can also read file asynchronously as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access). This is rather useless approach as I still merge everything to a single line, so I'm a bit speculating here when will comment on the results :)

```
|                Method | buffer |    Mean |       Gen 0 |      Gen 1 |     Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------------------- |------- |--------:|------------:|-----------:|----------:|----------:|
|      ReadFileToMemory |      ? | 1.919 s | 181000.0000 | 93000.0000 | 6000.0000 |   2.05 GB |
|   ReadFileEnumerating |      ? | 1.881 s | 314000.0000 |          - |         - |   1.38 GB |
| ReadFileToMemoryAsync |   4096 | 9.254 s | 248000.0000 | 68000.0000 | 6000.0000 |   1.92 GB |
| ReadFileToMemoryAsync |  16384 | 5.632 s | 215000.0000 | 61000.0000 | 6000.0000 |   1.72 GB |
| ReadFileToMemoryAsync |  65536 | 3.499 s | 196000.0000 | 54000.0000 | 4000.0000 |   1.62 GB |
```

```
    [RyuJitX64Job]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [IterationCount(1), InnerIterationCount(1), WarmupCount(0), InvocationCount(1), ProcessCount(1)]
    [StopOnFirstError]
    public class LogReaderBenchmarks
    {
        string file = @"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6483.tmp";

        [GlobalSetup()]
        public void Setup()
        {
            //file = Path.GetTempFileName(); <---- uncomment these lines to generate file first time.
            //Console.WriteLine(file);
            //LogFilesGenerator.GenerateLogFile(file);
        }

        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public string ReadFileToMemory() => File.ReadAllText(file);

        [Benchmark]
        [Arguments(1024*4)]
        [Arguments(1024 * 16)]
        [Arguments(1024 * 64)]
        public async Task<string> ReadFileToMemoryAsync(int buffer) => await ReadTextAsync(file, buffer);

        [Benchmark]
        public int ReadFileEnumerating() => File.ReadLines(file).Select(l => l.Length).Max();

        private async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath, int bufferSize)
        {
            using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
                bufferSize: bufferSize, useAsync: true))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int numRead;
                while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
                    sb.Append(text);
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see `ReadFileEnumerating` is the fastest. It allocates the same amount of memory as `ReadFileToMemory` but it is all in Gen 0, so GC can collect it faster, max memory consumption is much smaller than `ReadFileToMemory`.

Async read does not give any performance gain. If you need throughput, **don't** use it.

#### Split log entries

Regex is slow and memory hungry. Passing a huge string will make your application work slow. You can mitigate this problem and check each line of the file if it matches your Regex. You need to reconstruct the whole log entry though if it could be multiline.

Also you can introduce more efficient method that matches your string, check `customParseMatch` for example. I don't pretend it to be the most efficient, you may write a separate benchmark for predicate, but it already shows a good result comparing to `Regex` -  it is 10 times faster.

```
|                      Method |     Mean | Ratio |       Gen 0 |       Gen 1 |     Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------------------------- |---------:|------:|------------:|------------:|----------:|----------:|
|                SplitByRegex | 24.191 s |  1.00 | 426000.0000 | 119000.0000 | 4000.0000 |   2.65 GB |
|       SplitByRegexIterating | 16.302 s |  0.67 | 176000.0000 |  88000.0000 | 1000.0000 |   2.05 GB |
| SplitByCustomParseIterating |  2.385 s |  0.10 | 398000.0000 |           - |         - |   1.75 GB |
```

```
    [RyuJitX64Job]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [IterationCount(1), InnerIterationCount(1), WarmupCount(0), InvocationCount(1), ProcessCount(1)]
    [StopOnFirstError]
    public class LogParserBenchmarks
    {
        string file = @"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp6483.tmp";
        string[] lines;
        string text;
        Regex split_regex = new Regex(@"\s+(?=\d+: \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3} - )");

        [GlobalSetup()]
        public void Setup()
        {           
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
            text = File.ReadAllText(file);
        }

        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public string[] SplitByRegex() => split_regex.Split(text);

        [Benchmark]
        public int SplitByRegexIterating() =>
            parseLogEntries(lines, split_regex.IsMatch).Count();

        [Benchmark]
        public int SplitByCustomParseIterating() =>
            parseLogEntries(lines, customParseMatch).Count();

        public static bool customParseMatch(string line)
        {
            var refinedLine = line.TrimStart();
            var colonIndex = refinedLine.IndexOf(':');
            if (colonIndex < 0) return false;
            if (!int.TryParse(refinedLine.Substring(0,colonIndex), out var _)) return false;
            if (refinedLine[colonIndex + 1] != ' ') return false;
            if (!TimeSpan.TryParseExact(refinedLine.Substring(colonIndex + 2,12), @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var _)) return false;
            return true;
        }

        IEnumerable<string> parseLogEntries(IEnumerable<string> lines, Predicate<string> entryMatched)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (entryMatched(line) && builder.Length > 0)
                {
                    yield return builder.ToString();
                    builder.Clear();
                }
                builder.AppendLine(line);
            }
            if (builder.Length > 0)
                yield return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

#### Parallelism

If your log entries could be multi-line that is not trivial task and I'd leave it to other members to provide a code.

#### Summary

So iterating over each line and using a custom parse function gives us the best results so far. Let's make a benchmark and check how much did we gain:

```
|                      Method |     Mean |       Gen 0 |       Gen 1 |     Gen 2 | Allocated |
|---------------------------- |---------:|------------:|------------:|----------:|----------:|
|     ReadTextAndSplitByRegex | 29.070 s | 601000.0000 | 198000.0000 | 2000.0000 |    4.7 GB |
| ReadLinesAndSplitByFunction |  4.117 s | 713000.0000 |           - |         - |   3.13 GB |
```

```
[RyuJitX64Job]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    [IterationCount(1), InnerIterationCount(1), WarmupCount(0), InvocationCount(1), ProcessCount(1)]
    [StopOnFirstError]
    public class LogBenchmarks
    {
        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public string[] ReadTextAndSplitByRegex()
        {
            var text = File.ReadAllText(LogParserBenchmarks.file);
            return LogParserBenchmarks.split_regex.Split(text);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public int ReadLinesAndSplitByFunction()
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(LogParserBenchmarks.file);
            var entries = LogParserBenchmarks.parseLogEntries(lines, LogParserBenchmarks.customParseMatch);
            return entries.Count();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to try to improve on Fenixil's excellent and thorough answer.  I would like to point out that while regular expressions are great for some things, as is already apparent they aren't particularly efficient.  Below is how the regex you've given is resolved (according to the RegEx Buddy tool).

[image]

It takes a bit of work to match a regex.  This link [How a Regex Engine Works Internally](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) explains the process further.